# Synchronize local changes to remote database

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, data-synchronization

I got a requirement to setup 2-way data sync between main remote Postgresql DB and a local one. Main DB is used for multi-tenant access, and local db is used only by one tenant. So I need to sync only this tenant data. Local DB is installed on tenant's site and should be used only when internet connection is down. So, when there is internet connection, use remote DB and sync all the changes to local. When internet is down, switch to local DB. When internet is back online, sync local changes to remote.

I tried to figure out how to set this up, but it seems that Postgres replication isn't suitable for this case.

I need a tool that is capable of partial table sync both ways. Should I, maybe, consider changing DB design?

Comment: This is a classic `split-brain` problem. Perhaps the optimal solution in your case is to add some logic in the application - otherwise an employee of the tenant who is working from home (and thus has internet even when the tenant's office does not) can create records in the remote DB with the same ID(s) as other records in the local DB.

Comment: Remote DB is kinda "online-backup" for local DB, so in case of connection loss, changes on local DB have higher priority and can overwrite remote

Comment: Then maybe you can setup a replication where local DB is master and remote DB is slave. When connection is restored - replication will continue from where it stopped.